# How to get particular unique values from json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have my json like this..

```
{
"Project_details": [
    {
        "Project_ID": "1245353445",
        "Name": "Test1",
        "Releases": [
            {
                "sid_ratio": "5.0",
                "release_version": "13.2",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "2",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "2",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                "release_version": "14.1",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "3",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "3",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                "release_version": "14.2",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "0",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "0",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to get the unique release_version in one array..

And I need the keys "Project ID" and "Name" in another array..

How this can be possible using angularjs? these data I want to get it in controller and assign those arrays to $scope..

Comment: This isn't really Angular related though. What you want is to loop over an array and looks for stuff in it. Have you tried anything? Post the code that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing specific to angular. The final code (raw javascript):

```
var x = {
    "Project_details": [
        {
            "Project_ID": "1245353445",
            "Name": "Test1",
            "Releases": [
                {
                    "sid_ratio": "5.0",
                    "release_version": "13.2",
                    "pre_delivery": {
                        "total": "13",
                        "blocker": "2",
                        "critical": "2",
                        "major": "4",
                        "normal": "6",
                        "minor": "1"
                    },
                    "post_delivery": {
                        "total": "3",
                        "blocker": "2",
                        "critical": "0",
                        "major": "1",
                        "normal": "1",
                        "minor": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                    "release_version": "14.1",
                    "pre_delivery": {
                        "total": "13",
                        "blocker": "3",
                        "critical": "2",
                        "major": "4",
                        "normal": "6",
                        "minor": "1"
                    },
                    "post_delivery": {
                        "total": "3",
                        "blocker": "3",
                        "critical": "0",
                        "major": "1",
                        "normal": "1",
                        "minor": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                    "release_version": "14.2",
                    "pre_delivery": {
                        "total": "13",
                        "blocker": "0",
                        "critical": "2",
                        "major": "4",
                        "normal": "6",
                        "minor": "1"
                    },
                    "post_delivery": {
                        "total": "3",
                        "blocker": "0",
                        "critical": "0",
                        "major": "1",
                        "normal": "1",
                        "minor": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
var y = createMap(selectMany(x.Project_details.map(function (x) { return x.Releases; })).map(function (x) { return x.release_version; }));
console.log(Object.keys(y)); // "13.2" "14.1" "14.2"
function selectMany(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            result.push(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function createMap(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (result, key) {
        result[key] = true;
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

You basically needed the functions `selectMany` and `createMap`.

## More

I actually wrote it in TypeScript, its more fun to see the type transforms (but probably more complex for a beginner):

```
let x = {
"Project_details": [
    {
        "Project_ID": "1245353445",
        "Name": "Test1",
        "Releases": [
            {
                "sid_ratio": "5.0",
                "release_version": "13.2",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "2",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "2",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                "release_version": "14.1",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "3",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "3",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "sid_ratio": "15.0",
                "release_version": "14.2",
                "pre_delivery": {
                    "total": "13",
                    "blocker": "0",
                    "critical": "2",
                    "major": "4",
                    "normal": "6",
                    "minor": "1"
                },
                "post_delivery": {
                    "total": "3",
                    "blocker": "0",
                    "critical": "0",
                    "major": "1",
                    "normal": "1",
                    "minor": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}



let y = createMap(selectMany(x.Project_details.map(x=>x.Releases)).map(x=>x.release_version));
console.log(Object.keys(y));// "13.2" "14.1" "14.2"


function selectMany<T>(arr: T[][]): T[] {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            result.push(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function createMap(arr: string[]): { [string: string]: boolean } {
    return arr.reduce((result: { [string: string]: boolean }, key: string) => {
        result[key] = true;
        return result;
    }, <{ [string: string]: boolean }>{});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that question was accepted. And I love pure javascript. But I can't keep myself from providing an elegant solution with the use of **[LoDash](https://lodash.com/)**.

As I understand correctly, you want two different array.

Extract **release_version** in an array

```
_.pluck(data['Project_details'][0]['Releases'], 'release_version');
// ["13.2", "14.1", "14.2"]
```

Extract **Project_Id** and **Name**

```
_.pick(data['Project_details'][0], ['Project_ID', 'Name'])
// Object {Project_ID: "1245353445", Name: "Test1"}
```

The index `0` is used cause there only one row in your Project_details array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried this, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get the particular unique value from the Json using `angular.forEach`

```
var notificationcontent = [{"type":"success","title":"title","body":"Your deadline to open an Term deposit and save thousands in taxes is june 20th!","timeout":"0","bodyOutputType":"trustedHtml","clickHandler":""},

{"type":"error","title":"title","body":"This month, Your spent Rs.500.05 on restaurants. This exceeds your budget of Rs.300 by Rs.200.","timeout":"0","bodyOutputType":"trustedHtml","clickHandler":""},

{"type":"warning","title":"title","body":"This month, Your spent Rs.500.05 on Gas and Fuel. This exceeds your budget of Rs.800 by Rs.200.","timeout":"0","bodyOutputType":"trustedHtml","clickHandler":""}];

angular.forEach ( notificationcontent, function(value, key) {alert(value.type);console.log(value.body);});
```